# Count length of word without using Inbuilt functions

Tags: c#, string

This is a question I have come across and failed

Suppose say

```
string str = "wordcounter";
```

One can easily find the Length using `str.Length`

However, is it possible in C# to get the number of letters, without using any inbuilt functions like `Length`, `SubStr` etc

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use the inbuilt functions?

Comment: I tried `string temp = "Hello World";
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; temp[i] != '\0'; i++) ;
        Console.WriteLine(i);`
and was disappointed to find out that [C# Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228362.aspx) DO NOT contain a null terminating character. I've included my attempt here for future reference.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you could write a loop and increment a counter inside this loop:

```
int numberOfLetters = 0;
foreach (var c in str)
{
    numberOfLetters++;
}
// at this stage numberOfLetters will contain the number of letters 
// that the string contains
```

there is also another way:

```
int numberOfLetters = str.ToCharArray().Length;
```

there is also another, even crazier way using the [SysStringByteLen function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221097%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which operates on a [BSTR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Strings in .NET are layed out in memory by using a 4 byte integer containing the length of the string followed by that many 2 byte UTF-16 characters representing each character. This is similar to how [BSTRs are stored](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/12/52976.aspx). So:

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("oleaut32.dll")]
    static extern uint SysStringByteLen(IntPtr bstr);

    static void Main()
    {
        string str = "wordcounter";
        var bstr = Marshal.StringToBSTR(str);

        // divide by 2 because the SysStringByteLen function returns 
        // number of bytes and each character takes 2 bytes (UTF-16)
        var numberOfLetters = SysStringByteLen(bstr) / 2; 
        Console.WriteLine(numberOfLetters);
    }
}
```

Obviously doing something like this instead of using the built-in `Length` function should never be done in any real production code and the code shown here should not be taken seriously.

Comment: True. Why would anyone want to do it manually when there is a built-in property is beyond me. I am not even sure if this method that you and I proposed would work with all Unicode characters. I would stick with String.Length

Comment: `int numberOfLetters = str.ToCharArray().Length;` But in this line of code still we have inbuilt function.

Answer (score 7):

My answer is bit late, but I would like to post the same. Though all above mentioned solutions are correct, but I believe that the IL of the foreach does knows about the length of the iterable before iterating it. Talking of a pure solution, here's mine:

```
    private int stringLength(string str) {
        int length = 0;
        bool done = false;
        do {
            try {
                char c = str[length];
                length++;
            } catch (IndexOutOfRangeException) {
                done = true;
            }
        } while(!done);
        return length;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

How about?

```
int myOwnGetStringLength(String str)
{
    int count = 0;
    foreach(Char c in str)
        count++;
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

not very fast but yo can always loop and count the number of caracter contained.

```
int counter = 0;
foreach (var caracter in str)
{
    counter ++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string Name = "He is palying in a ground.";
        char[] characters = Name.ToCharArray();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = Name.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            sb.Append(characters[i]);
        }
        Console.Write(sb.ToString());
        Console.Read();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a string to find its lenght");
        string ch = Console.ReadLine();
        Program p = new Program();
        int answer = p.run(ch);
        Console.WriteLine(answer);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    public int run(string ch)
    {
        int count = 0;
        foreach (char c in ch)
        {
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My general solution involves without using 'foreach' or 'StringBuilder' (which are C# specific) or without catching any exception.

```
            string str = "wordcounter";
            str += '\0';
            int x = 0;
            while (str[x] != '\0')
                x++;
            Console.WriteLine(x);     //Outputs 11
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string test = "test";

        //string as char array:
        //iterate through char collection
        foreach (char c in test)
        {
           //do something
        }
        //access elements by index
        Console.WriteLine("Contents of char array : {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", test[0], test[1], test[2], test[3]);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any new information in this answer in comparison to previous answers?

Answer (score -1):

```
namespace ConsoleApplication {  
class Program {  
    static void Main(string[] args) {  
        string testString = "testing";  
        int x = 0;  
        foreach(char c in testString) {  
            x++;  
        }  
        Console.WriteLine("\nLength Of String:{0}", (x));  
        Console.Read();  
    }  
}
```